# update select not working in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement to do an update based on some order. I have created a Query for this in Oracle, The Query is given below

```
update (select work_id work_id, task_id task_id  from TRANSACTION s where 
        s.task_id is null order by s.dynamic_key) set task_id=2, work_id=SEQ_TRANS.NEXTVAL.
```

In the above Query - SEQ_TRANS is sequence

This Query is working in oracle. But not working in PostgreSQL.

I would like to get the equivalent query which support both in oracle and PostgreSQL, This query should do update based on order.

Comment: There is no query that would work unchanged in both DBMS.

Comment: You cannot update a sub-select directly in PostgreSQL. Also, it is not possible to do any `UPDATE` in a specific order. PostgreSQL has the ability to defer constraints instead (most of the time, unique constraints make developers want to update in a specific order). -- But if I'm guessing right, you want the order because of the sequence value generation. If that's right, you can use a sub-select in the [`FROM` clause of the `UPDATE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) (as sub-selects *can* have an order). However, this approach might not work in Oracle.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I need to update sequence in order.

Comment: Do you have sample with sub select?